# Mod Rewrite: How do you rewrite out of the URL's home directory?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a directory structure on our VPS like this:

```
/www
  /site_one
  /site_two
```

And going to www.siteone.com brings you to /www/site_one/ on the server. I'd like to use mod_rewrite to point a request for www.siteone.com/thing/ to the directory /www/site_two/thing.

I've tried a basic rewrite like:

```
RewriteRule ^page.html$ /www/site_two/new_page.html
```

but / refers to /www/site_one/

Is there a way to get it to serve the page from the directory I'd like?

**EDIT**

To answer the questions below:

@Ignacio I'm not sure if I left anything important out. Brand new to mod_rewrite.

@outis: Yes both sites are virutal hosts. www.site_one.com is mapped to /www/site_one/ and www.site_two.com is mapped ot /www/site_two

Comment: Something there smells funny... Did you leave out some critical piece of information?

Comment: How are the domains mapped to their respective document roots? Are the different sites virtual hosts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a full URL, which implicitly redirects:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*\.)site_one\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?(thing(/.*)?) http://%1site_two.com/$1
```

To achieve this without redirection, the documents in /www/site_two must be accessible via URLs in the site_one.com domain; a symlink from /www/site_one/site_two to /www/site_two might do it.

Comment: That's slick. I would not have thought of adding a symlink to get the desired effect. I'd give ya another +1 if I could!

Comment: Don't forget to allow following of symlinks should you decide to go that route.

Comment: The symlink idea has a smell to it. How good an idea it is depends on the relationship between the sites, which should determine whether a site_two resource should be accessible via a site_one URL. At the very least, external site_one URLs with "^/site_two" should be disallowed. Another source of smell is duplicate content, which affects search engine ratings (http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=66359). All in all, external redirects are the way to go.